# System-generated email for Azure Logic app

Tags: azure, email, office365, azure-logic-apps

I would like to know whether there is a possibility for a Logic app with system assigned managed identity to create its own email address from which it would send an email to predefined users. Or maybe to use some kind of office 365 email for sending notifications that would not be managed directly by me but also would be maintained in that way so it could be used at any time.

The point is that currently, I have a perfectly working logic app that sends emails. But those emails are sent from an employee's email address that authorized Office 365 connection in the logic app. Since this is dependent on his or her email address if something happens to the email (employee changes jobs and email address needs to be decommissioned) logic app won't be executed and these emails which are critical for us to get will not be delivered.

Is there a way so the logic app would not be dependent on the email address of one person but instead of that on some kind of system-generated email address for sending emails?

Comment: you could use the [sendMail Graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-sendmail?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http). you would need to grant ` Mail.Send (Application)` permission to the managed identity. Then your logic app could use a generic email to send email from

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several options. The most popular is the SendGrid service

https://docs.sendgrid.com/for-developers/partners/microsoft-azure-2021

There is a free option that includes 100 emails per day.